# Range Header Must Use Appropriate Property or Method

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest, qradar

I've searched high and low and asked on the product forums, but cannot seem to figure this out.

Using PowerShell 5 I'm attempting to limit my results by using a range header in the way the API documentation indicates. However, I receive the following error when I try to use it.

> "The 'RANGE' header must be modified using the appropriate property or
>   method. Parameter name: name"

I've tried:

```
$headers = @{
    SEC= $apiKey
    range="items=0-49"
}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $global:URI -ContentType 'application/json' -Header $headers
```

and...

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add('Accept','Application/Json')
    $headers.Add('RANGE','items=0-49')
    $headers.Add('SEC',$ApiKey)
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $global:URI -Headers $headers -Method get
```

Also, here's the curl example given within the API documentation:

curl -s -X GET -u USERNAME -H 'Range: items=0-49' -H 'Version: 10.0' -H 'Accept: application/json' 'https://product.com/api/s/of'

Really appreciate any pointers on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you print out `$Headers` do you see the expected values?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. When using an array the name shows range and value shows items=0-49. When showing the dictionary key is range and value is items=0-49.

Comment: i've read that there are sites that will show you what your are actually sending ... you may need to find a way to see what the other end is getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in PowerShell. I found this blog page: https://sethjackson.github.io/2017/01/18/header-woes/

The workaround according to this page:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Method = "GET"
$request.Headers.Add("SEC", $apiKey)

# add range header
$request.AddRange("items", 0, $count)

$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try this I get an error: "Exception setting "Headers": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Net.WebHeaderCollection"."" for this line: $request.Headers += @{ "SEC" = $apiKey }

Comment: Try to use `Add` (see updated answer) or `$request.Headers["SEC"] = $apiKey`